# How to iterate over MvcSiteMapNodes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a partial view which I'm using to render out a sub-set of the MvcSiteMapNodes in my MvcSitemap.

However I am having trouble iterating over the MvcSiteMap nodes.

If I use;

```
var nodes = new MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapHelperModel();
```

it returns an empty collection.

How do you iterate over the MvcSiteMapNodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using the following;

```
var nodes = SiteMap.CurrentNode.RootNode.ChildNodes;
        foreach(SiteMapNode node in nodes)
        {
            MvcSiteMapProvider.MvcSiteMapNode mvcNode = (MvcSiteMapProvider.MvcSiteMapNode)node;
```

Answer (score 0):

In v4, the location has changed because the Microsoft sitemap provider is no longer used. There is also no longer a need to cast.

```
var nodes = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.RootNode.ChildNodes;
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
   // Do something with the node's values - no need to cast anymore.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is almost @NightOwl888's solution, but without `CurrentNode`:

```
var nodes = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.RootNode.ChildNodes;
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
   // ...
}
```

Bonus: you can also use LINQ to get to certain part / subset of the node tree to traverse, like:

```
var projectNode = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.RootNode.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.Key == "Projects").FirstOrDefault();
```